# Cmake is not building an executable

Tags: c++, github, cmake, executable

I am trying to use the code here https://github.com/usuaero/MachUp
I have followed all the pre requisites required but when I try to build the executable I get this error.  Any advice would be helpful.  I am not sure what "[-Dndv=]" this is, is it a folder that cmake is looking for a can't find?

```
PS C:\Program Files\MachUp-master> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" [-Dndv=<ndv>]
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Program Files/MachUp-master/[-Dndv=<ndv>]" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
PS C:\Program Files\MachUp-master>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `[-Dndv=<ndv>]` is something you've copied from some instructions somewhere? Generally the convention is that the square brackets indicate an optional argument and the angle brackets indicate a value you need to supply so you should be passing `-Dndv=some_value` or just omitting that argument completely

Comment: yes, their read me says 
From the command prompt navigate to the MachUp directory
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" [-Dndv=<ndv>]
mingw32-make
If successful, the executable (MachUp.out.exe) will be created in the MachUp/bin/ directory

Comment: You should not be building anything directly in `C:\Program Files`

Answer (score 0):

Actually their README have incorrect CMake command line.
If you are running CMake in the source directory you need to pass `.` as a directory to build.
The `[...]` means it is an optional argument you can pass, just remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very good with command line. When you say pass . as the directory to build, what does that mean?  Do I need to type cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .

Comment: Yes, exactly, this should work

Comment: this is what I get    C:\Program Files\MachUp-master> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .
CMake Error: Unable to (re)create the private pkgRedirects directory:
C:/Program Files/MachUp-master/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects
PS C:\Program Files\MachUp-master>

Comment: @TheDude you probably don't have the necessary permissions. Using program files as a build directory is probably unwise

Comment: @ Alan Britles, you were correct, I moved the out of Program Files and it worked.  Thanks everyone for your assistance, much appreciated